# What is the replacement of setDataFormatResolver for ExtendedCamelContext?

Tags: spring-boot, maven, apache-camel, java-17, camel-jackson

With Apache Camel on `3.20` version I used to use the `setDataFormatResolver` method, which was from `ExtendedCamelContext`, to set a custom data format in `CamelContext`. But since `4.0.0-M3` version, this method has been removed from the class. I'm wondering, how could I replace this method to some similar?
I searched at the documentation, but I didn't find the answer I'm looking for.

Another question about the same subject, now that `ExtendedCamelContext` is decoupled from `CamelContext`, when `ExtendedCamelContext` is instantiated the `CamelContext` will keep being one single instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set a specific `DataFormatResolver` in Camel 4, you need to call the method [ExtendedCamelContext.html#addContextPlugin](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.camel/camel-api/latest/org/apache/camel/ExtendedCamelContext.html#addContextPlugin(java.lang.Class,T)).

So assuming that the name of your custom class is `CustomDataFormatResolver`, the code would look like the following code snippet:

```
context.getCamelContextExtension().addContextPlugin(
    DataFormatResolver.class, new CustomDataFormatResolver()
);
```

Where `context` is your Camel context instance.

> Another question about the same subject, now that ExtendedCamelContext is decoupled from CamelContext, when ExtendedCamelContext is instantiated the CamelContext will keep being one single instance?

Yes there is only one `ExtendedCamelContext` per `CamelContext`.